# How to create an array of values in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, libreoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I'm using **LibreOffice 5.1.4.2 Calc** and need to calculate the *internal rate of return* for a certain payment (say, in cell `A1`), a certain number of times (say, `100`).

If I had the value repeated 100 times (say, in `A1:A100`), I could do:

```
=IRR(A1:A100)
```

But it seems odd (what if it's 100,000 times?).

The problem is, the function `IIR` expects [“an array containing the values”](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Financial_Functions_Part_One#IRR).

**How can I pass along to `IRR` an array of the value in `A1` repeated `100` times?**

Comment: I believe I've been confused what you were after here, sorry about that.

In your example above do the cells A1:A100 all contain a single fixed payment?  That is, the spreadsheet equivalent of  { 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 ... 95x ... 7 }.

Is your question "What if I needed { 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 ... 100,995x ... 7 } instead"?  Now that I read more carefully, that appears to be how Jim DeLaHunt has interpreted the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking Libreoffice Calc to do something it cannot do.

In LibreOffice Calc, an array is a "a linked range of cells on a spreadsheet containing values" (per [Help article *Array Functions*](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions#What_is_an_Array.3F)). There is such a thing as an "Inline Array Constant", but that's for putting values into an array. `IRR()` is not an array function, it is a single-valued function which takes an array as an argument.

I think LibreOffice Calc wants to you allocate those 100 (or 100,000) cells with the same value.

You can populate the cells in various ways. I would put the value in the first cell, then give the second cell a formula that read from the first cell with an absolute reference, then fill that second cell down 100 (or 100,000) times to get the array I needed. All I have to change is the value in the first cell, and it gets propagated through the array.

If you really want to type a concise formula to calculate the Internal Rate of Return for 100,000 payments of the same amount, maybe LibreOffice isn't the best tool for the job. It's a spreadsheet. A programming language, like the Python language and the [`numpy.irr()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.irr.html) function, might work better.

Comment: Thank you, @jim-delahunt. I still find it odd that there's no elegant way to do what I need (without actually using *n* cells), so I'm not accepting your answer as the good one just yet, in case someone else weighs in on this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to write the array directly in your formula.
Calc refers to this as an *"inline array constant"*.

A simple 3x2 example is

```
{1;2;3|"a";"b";"c"}.
```

[Calc's Documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions#Using_Inline_Array_Constants_in_Formulas) has full details...

Comment: Again, my problem is that I may need to use a very long array. Imagine 300x2,000 instead. This syntax doesn't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which creates a repeating array based on cells in the spreadsheet.

I haven't written any code for Calc, so I'm not familiar with the syntax used, but in pseudo-code:

```
function repeat( value, amount ) -> { value | value | value ... value }
```

... then call this code from IRR.

Alternatively, create a function that does everything:

```
function repeatIrr( value, amount ) -> value
```

... and call that from the spreadsheet.

Comment: @tripu I assume this isn't what you are personally after (feel free to correct me on that!).  I'm adding this answer in as it would be a solution, and may be acceptable to someone in a similar situation.

Comment: ... personally if somebody else is interested in filling in the implementation details for Calc in this solution I'd love to see them!